# Blank screen short store in folder in php

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload screen short from the clipboard with JavaScript.but screen short store blank.[screen short store in folder like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLSrE.png)
Screen short store in folder blank.

my javascript code

```
<script>
    function retrieveImageFromClipboardAsBlob(pasteEvent, callback)
    {
        if(pasteEvent.clipboardData == false)
        {
            if(typeof(callback) == "function")
            {
                callback(undefined);
            }
        };
        var items = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;
        if(items == undefined)
        {
            if(typeof(callback) == "function")
            {
                callback(undefined);
            }
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
        {
            if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue;
            var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
            if(typeof(callback) == "function")
            {
                callback(blob);
            }
        }   
    }
    window.addEventListener("paste", function(e)
    {
        retrieveImageFromClipboardAsBlob(e, function(imageBlob)
        {
            if(imageBlob)
            {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function()
                {
                    canvas.width = this.width;
                    canvas.height = this.height;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                };
                var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                img.src = URLObj.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
                document.getElementById('canvasimg').value = canvas.toDataURL();
                $( "mycanvass" ).change();

            }
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: Then how to load image?
Piz help me.

Comment: Php server side code like this.

if($content_type == 'image/png')
  {
   $type = ".png";
   $content = base64_decode($content);
   $im = @imagecreatefromstring($content);
   if ($im !== false) 
   {
    if($image_file!=='')
    {
     if(imagepng($im,$image_path.$image_file.$type))
     {
      $RESPONSE_INNER_DATA['imagefile'] = $image_file.$type;
     }
    }
    imagedestroy($im);
   }
  }